# Could not load type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Telemetry.Web.ApplicationInsightsModule'

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have a Azure service which I developed using the C#.Net. When I compiled the solution it does it without any errors.

But when I run it, it throws the below error:

> *Could not load type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Telemetry.Web.ApplicationInsightsModule'*

The following is the section where it points to when I run the solution .

```
<system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
     <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="/Error/Error.html" />
     <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.5" />
     <httpModules>
        <add name="ApplicationInsights" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Telemetry.Web.ApplicationInsightsModule" />
     </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the Application Insights API nuget package installed

1. Open the context menu of your project in Visual Studio solution explorer.
2. Choose Manage NuGet Packages.
3. View Online packages and search for "Application Insights". Include the quotation marks.
4. Choose Application Insights Telemetry SDK for Services.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It is fixed by re installing the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights nuget package.